# How to convert Avro to an SQL batch update?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to convert an inputs Avro (array of Avro records) into a batch of upsert statemenets. Is there a processor that can do this?

> [Read External DB (RDBMS)]->[Avro to Upsert batch]->[Local DB]

What I found is that the records can be formatted with sql.N.args.type & name before the PutSQL. With this approach, is there a processor or a trick that can make this clean?

> [Read External DB (RDBMS)]->[Split into 1]->[Convert Avro to
>   sql.N.args.type and name format]->[SetAttribute:
>   sql.statement=SQL]->[Local DB]

In the 2nd case I'm stuck at [Convert Avro to sql.N.args.type and name format] and I'm trying to resist the urge to use ExecuteScript... What is the simplest way forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to generate SQL (to do an upsert vs an insert for example), you could use ConvertJSONToSQL (assuming your content is JSON) which does all the sql.args.N stuff for you. If you use ExecuteSQLRecord or QueryDatabaseTableRecord you can get your source DB information as JSON (by using a JsonRecordSetWriter) vs the non-record-based versions which only output Avro. Otherwise you'd need a ConvertAvroToJSON before ConvertJSONToSQL.

Comment: Thanks for the precise answer! I ended up using [QueryDatabaseTable]->[PutDatabaseRecord]. Your solution helped me get rid of the splits I was doing to batches as well. Thanks again! :)